# Disable Keyboard on visual basic application

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I´m developing a visual basic forms application, I call itself "Robot", and I have some problems with it.

The Robot has a Webbrowser object that navigates to a website and searches for info.

I need to disable the keyboard because when I press some keys like "Delete", "F5", "Enter", "Supr",

the Webbrowser gets that keys entries causing the Robot to crash or malfunction.

How can I disable the keyboard?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't disable the keyboard.  You're actually looking for a headless browser.

Comment: Just don't make it visible and you can never have this problem.  Or don't use a WebBrowser at all.

Comment: Check out the keypress event

Comment: I really need to use the webbrowser. I think @SLaks is right. If I just use the Hide() function for the Forms, the keyboard should not be a problem. I´m also trying with the keypress event, It will be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Since there has not been an answer in the last two days,
Try this...

```
 Private Sub WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown

    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.F5
            MessageBox.Show("F5")''do whatever here....
        Case Keys.Delete
            MessageBox.Show("DELETE")''and here....
        Case Keys.Enter
            MessageBox.Show("ENTER") ''and here
        Case Else
            ''nothing '' make an else statement here
    End Select

    ''//Not too sure what Supr means, but nevertheless this should get you on your way.

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Werdna. I´m trying this code. "Supr" is the key just behind the "Insert"